# Script Output Displays Inconsistent Time for Modified Date Column Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, datetime, sharepoint-2010, last-modified

I have a script that outputs to CSV all items and all files from a site shown below. This script also displays current and previous versions of a file:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl

    $excludeLists = @("Master Page Gallery",
                "Workflows",
                "Workflow History"
                 )

    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        if($excludeLists -notcontains $list.Title)
        {
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
            {
                $firstPass = $true

                foreach($version in $item.Versions)
                {
                    $created = ""
                    $authorName = ""

                    if($firstPass)
                    {
                        $created = ($item["Created"] -as [datetime]).DateTime

                        $personField = $item.Fields.GetField("Author");
                        $authorObject = $personField.GetFieldValue($item["Author"]);
                        $authorName = $authorObject.LookupValue;                    

                        $firstPass = $false
                    }

                    $userField = $version.Fields.GetField("Editor");
                    $editorObject = $userField.GetFieldValue($version["Editor"]);
                    $editorName = $editorObject.LookupValue;

                    $localOffset = +5;
                    $modified = $version["Modified"] -as [datetime];

                    if($modified.IsDaylightSavingTime())
                    {
                        $localOffset += 1;
                    }

                    $modifiedLocal = $modified.addHours(-$localOffset);

                    $data = @{
                        "Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $authorName 
                        "Created Date" = $created
                        "Modified By" = $editorName
                        "Modified Date" = ($modifiedLocal -as[datetime]).DateTime
                        "Item Name" = $item.Name
                    }

                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"
                }
            }
            $web.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

Get-DocInventory -siteUrl "http://contoso.com/sites/depts/HBG" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\AuditReport.csv
```

Below is a sample output of the script:

[image]

Also, below is the Version History of this file in excel format:

[image]

When I compared the output and the Version History I have noticed the versions 1-3 are displaying time 1hour ahead. On the other hand, versions 4-7 of the file displays the correct date/time.

I was thinking that it may be because of daylight savings and so I commented out this portion:

```
if($modified.IsDaylightSavingTime())
                        {
                            $localOffset += 1;
                        }
```

But I still get the same output. This issue happens to some files while others are displaying correct date/time. I have tried to research but could not come to an answer. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the value of `$modfied.IsDaylightSavingTime()` is actually different when it's supposed to be?

Comment: I ran the script with and without that line you mentioned and to be honest I did not see a difference at all in date/time in the Modified Date column at all.

Comment: Right, and that leads me to believe that maybe the value is not what you think (maybe it's always `$true` or always `$false`), so I'm wondering if you've confirmed that its value actually changes for the dates you expect it to.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Did you try setting your time value to UTC and see if the times line up?